# Skydome and Ambient Intensity (Unity)

Tags: unity, lighting, sky

I've made a custom skydome in my game. For all my lights I have set them to not affect the skydome. The only thing affecting the skydome is the ambient light.

For my game I have ambient intensity at 0.8, but this makes my skydome much darker than the original texture. What I want to do is to set the ambient intensity for the skydome to 1.0 and for all other objects to 0.8.

Is there any way I can say before drawing the skydome set ambient intensity to 1.0, and right after set it back to 0.8? Or is there perhaps a simpler solution? :)

Comment: Can you not make it ignore the lighting in the skydome material?

Comment: I changed the material to use "Unlit/Texture" shader, and now it looks exactly like I want. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The skydome material's shader should be set to Unlit/Texture to ignore the lighting.